# spring secuirty allowed login only if brawser support cookie

Tags: session, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-security

I am using spring security. I want to allow login only if the browser supports cookies.
If the browser does not support cookies then I do not want allow the user to login.
Please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<http disable-url-rewriting="true">`. This will prevent session id being append to the URL.